# Could a Ferroliquid airlock work?

Tags: habitat, airlock

After looking at the [previous question on liquid airlocks](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/10749/could-liquid-airlocks-work), I noted that the main problem with technology is that the force of gravity is far too weak on any body that an airlock would be a useful piece of equipment for the liquid airlock to work effectively.

So, lets replace gravity with the magnetic force, and the liquid with a ferroliquid, and see what happens.

The obvious advantages of such an airlock would be that it could be used in a continuous manner, perhaps for mining operations (for moving large machinery and for moving a conveyor belt of minerals).

Would this work in a vacuum?

Comment: If it is magnetically controlled does that mean electronics have to be heavily shielded to pass through? Also, most machinery is made out of metal so that could be a problem for magnetic fields. Or is the idea to have the magnetic field turned off when passing through? Add a figure to clarify things a bit.

Comment: If you lose power does that mean you lose your atmosphere?

Comment: @BrianLynch: This wouldn't restrict all metals, only strong ferromagnetics (like steel) - which isn't all that common in space use anyway (usually replaced with titanium). The picture would be the same as in the linked question, just the "Floor slab" segment under the airlock would be replaced with a strong electromagnet.

Comment: @BrianLynch No. Its not magnetically controlled. Its completely passive. As for a diagram, look at the link, and replace the liquid with a ferroliquid, and replace gravity with a magnetic field.

Comment: @GdD Only if you use electromagnets that are directly tied to your main power grid.

Comment: @Aron: Something needs to produce the magnetic field: either an electromagnet or really enormous fixed magnets. OTOH, when using electromagnet, you can always add a hatch on top, that automatically closes if the electromagnet fails, giving you time to perform repairs.

Comment: @SF. Or a really really cold super conducting electromagnet. If only we could find some way to keep things cold in space...

Comment: @SF Ah yes, of course. What about electronics?

Comment: @BrianLynch would an airlock that cannot transport electronics be useless? How about rocks?

Comment: @BrianLynch: Only magnetic data storage would be endangered by damage. Most electronics would work, some might fail and need to be switched off for the transfer. Only moving it fast enough to induce considerable current would create risk of damage, but with ferroliquid viscosity, "moving it fast" is quite unrealistic.

Comment: Nope, can't see why it wouldn't be useful still, just curious to know. Maybe electronics aren't even that vulnerable, you just need proper shielding for any storage.

Comment: @SF Nice, that is true. It makes me wonder if you could even setup currents (fluid currents, I mean) so that you end up with some kind of pseudo natural convection cycle and use that as an elevator itself. Like a lava lamp.

Comment: Meanwhile, I'm trying to imagine building a solid block of 4 tons worth of neodymium magnet on Earth, then bringing it to the Moon. It would make for a great comedy movie.

Comment: Discussions like this go great in [The Pod Bay](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9682/the-pod-bay), our main chat room. As you can see, it got long for a comments section, and as such eventually most of it will get cleaned up for the sake of brevity and clarity. OTOH, in the chat room discussions are preserved and can be referred back to later, other people can chime in, and so on. I invite you to come by (or even start your own if you want). :)

Comment: @SF. Neodymium is only rare on earth because all of it sank during the early days of Earth. On the moon, where it's cooler, I think all the neodymium is evenly distributed.

Comment: @Aron: Compare mass of the magnet vs mass of machinery required to make such magnet from scratch in space. Although certainly transport of such machinery would have less... comedic value.